# Probability of obtaining a specific string, Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability

In a book I found this:

$\omega=$ "$k$ ones followed by $n-k$ zeroes"

$A_i$ = success on trial $i$ = the set of all sequences with a one in the $i$th coordinate.

$P\{\omega\} = P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ...\cap A_k \cap A_{k+1}^c \cap ... \cap A_{n}^c) = P(A_1)P(A_2)...P(A_k)P(A_{k+1}^c)...P(A_n^c) = p^kq^{n-k}$

I don't understand this reasoning. Can someone please explain?

In particular, I dont get why the complements appear.

I assume it has something to do with independence of trials, but why include complements only for $k+1$ onwards?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey. Can you provide a bit more context? For instance, what is $\omega$? How did the sets $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n$ come up?

Comment: @Mankind sorry. my mistake.  updated the question with more info. thank you.

Comment: think i got it. Complements account for the zeroes in the sequence. right?

Comment: Yeah, you got it right. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your possible events are binary strings of length $n$, and you want to find the probability that you draw the string $\omega$, which is $k$ ones followed by $n-k$ zeroes.

You let $A_i$ be the event that you obtain a success in the $i$th trial, which means that the $i$th entry in the string is a $1$.

Notice that this means that the complement $A_i^c$ signifies that the $i$th entry in the string is a $0$, so since only the last $n-k$ entries are $0$, you want to use the complements for the last $n-k$ entries.

You are right about the independence, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

What they are saying refers to set of trials in which elements $s_i$ of a finite number of sets $S_1, S_2 \ldots S_n$ -- but $n$ can be arbitrarily large, thus the $\omega$ -- are  chosen, and one notes which ones of those are members of corresponding subsets $ A_1 \subseteq S_1, A_2 \subseteq S_2, \ldots A_n \subseteq S_n$.  The key characteristic of a Bernoulli trial is that the probability that $s_i \in A_i$
is independent of $i$ and of all the other $s_k$; call that probability $p$.  Each $s_i$ represents one Bernoulli trial. For conveniences we write $1-p = q$.

The equation you present says that if we re-order the trials such that each "success" (each case where $s_i \in A_i$) appears before any failure (any case where $s_i \not\in A_i$) then the probability of that specific arrangement with exactly $k$ successes is $p^kq^{n-k}$.

Of course, it is much more common to be interested in the overall probability of $k$ successes out of $n$ trials; by re-ordering to this one specific order we have collapsed $\binom{n}{k}$ possible results to this one case.  We have written the probability of $k$ **specific** successes among $n$ trials. So you will more often find the expression
$$P(k \mbox{ successes}) = \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}$$